# Accessing actual server response from Angular $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

I have an API built in Laravel which returns JSON in a format such as this:

```
{
  "data":{
    "errors":{
      "username":"The username has already been taken.",
      "email":"The email has already been taken."
    }
  },
  "success":true,
  "status":400
}
```

In this case, I'm trying to create a user with a username and email address which already exists. This is the Angular $resource code I'm using inside my controller for that:

```
var user = new User({
    username: $scope.user.username,
    email: $scope.user.email,
    password: $scope.user.password
});

var response = user.$save(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}, function(data) {
    if (data.status === 400) {
        angular.forEach(data.data.data.errors, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
});
```

So what this is doing is sending a POST request to `/users` on the API and if it comes back with a non-200 status code, it's checking if it's a 400 code which means a validation error and `console.log`'ing those error messages. Sure enough, I get the error messages output to the console.

What I'm wondering is, if there's a better way to access the error messages than `data.data.data.errors`. Seen as the API wraps the response data in a `data` field, and Angular returns the `$resource` of the request rather than the actual server response, it leads to a rather unsightly amount of properties being used to get the error messages.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer is 'no'. However, if it were me I would probably shuffle some of the variables to make things a bit nicer.

```
user.$save(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}, function(response) {
    if (response.status === 400) {
        var data = response.data.data
        angular.forEach(data.errors, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
});
```

If I had control over the api i would not be wrapping the `errors` in the redundant tertiary `data` object. This gives an entirely acceptable bit of code imo.

```
{
  "errors":{
    "username":"The username has already been taken.",
    "email":"The email has already been taken."
  },
  "success":true,
  "status":400
}

user.$save(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}, function(response) {
    var data = response.data
    if (data.status === 400) {
        angular.forEach(data.errors, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
});
```